# SwiftUI State var array not updating child views

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-state

For some reason I don't understand, when I add/remove items from a `@State var` in `MainView`, the `OutterView`s are not being updated properly.

What I am trying to achieve is that the user can only "flag" (select) one item at a time. For instance, when I click on "item #1" it will be flagged. If I click on another item then "item #1" will not be flagged anymore but only the new item I just clicked.

[image]

Currently, my code shows all items as if they were flagged even when they are not anymore. The following code has the minimum structure and functionality I'm implementing for `MainView`, `OutterView`, and `InnerView`.

I've tried using `State var`s instead of the computed property in `OutterView`, but it doesn't work. Also, I tried using a `var` instead of the computed property in `OutterView`and initialized it in `init()` but also doesn't work.

Hope you can help me to find what I am doing wrong.
Thanks!

```
struct MainView: View {
    @State var flagged: [String] = []
    
    var data: [String] = ["item #1", "item #2", "item #3", "item #4", "item #5"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 50) {
            VStack {
                ForEach(data, id:\.self) { text in
                    OutterView(text: text, flag: flagged.contains(text)) { (flag: Bool) in
                        if flag {
                            flagged = [text]
                        } else {
                            if let index = flagged.firstIndex(of: text) {
                                flagged.remove(at: index)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Text("Flagged: \(flagged.description)")
            
            Button(action: {
                flagged = []
            }, label: {
                Text("Reset flagged")
            })
        }
    }
}

struct OutterView: View {
    @State private var flag: Bool
    
    private let text: String
    private var color: Color { flag ? Color.green : Color.gray }
    private var update: (Bool)->Void
    
    var body: some View {
        InnerView(color: color, text: text)
            .onTapGesture {
                flag.toggle()
                update(flag)
            }
    }
    
    init(text: String, flag: Bool = false, update: @escaping (Bool)->Void) {
        self.text = text
        self.update = update
        _flag = State(initialValue: flag)
    }
}

struct InnerView: View {
    let color: Color
    let text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .padding()
            .background(
                Capsule()
                    .fill(color))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple version that does what you're looking for (explained below):

```
struct Item : Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var flagged = false
    var title : String
}

class StateManager : ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [Item(title: "Item #1"),Item(title: "Item #2"),Item(title: "Item #3"),Item(title: "Item #4"),Item(title: "Item #5")]
    
    func singularBinding(forIndex index: Int) -> Binding<Bool> {
        Binding<Bool> { () -> Bool in
            self.items[index].flagged
        } set: { (newValue) in
            self.items = self.items.enumerated().map { itemIndex, item in
                var itemCopy = item
                if index == itemIndex {
                    itemCopy.flagged = newValue
                } else {
                    //not the same index
                    if newValue {
                        itemCopy.flagged = false
                    }
                }
                return itemCopy
            }
        }
    }
    
    func reset() {
        items = items.map { item in
            var itemCopy = item
            itemCopy.flagged = false
            return itemCopy
        }
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    @ObservedObject var stateManager = StateManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 50) {
            VStack {
                ForEach(Array(stateManager.items.enumerated()), id:\.1.id) { (index,item) in
                    OutterView(text: item.title, flag: stateManager.singularBinding(forIndex: index))
                }
            }
            
            Text("Flagged: \(stateManager.items.filter({ $0.flagged }).map({$0.title}).description)")
            
            Button(action: {
                stateManager.reset()
            }, label: {
                Text("Reset flagged")
            })
        }
    }
}

struct OutterView: View {
    var text: String
    @Binding  var flag: Bool
    private var color: Color { flag ? Color.green : Color.gray }
    
    var body: some View {
        InnerView(color: color, text: text)
            .onTapGesture {
                flag.toggle()
            }
    }
}

struct InnerView: View {
    let color: Color
    let text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .padding()
            .background(
                Capsule()
                    .fill(color))
    }
}
```

What's happening:

1. There's a `Item` that has an ID for each item, the flagged state of that item, and the title
2. `StateManager` keeps an array of those items. It also has a custom binding for each index of the array. For the `getter`, it just returns the state of the model at that index. For the `setter`, it makes a new copy of the item array. Any time a checkbox is set, it unchecks all of the other boxes.
3. The `ForEach` now gets an enumeration of the `items`. This could be done without enumeration, but it was easy to write the custom binding by index like this. You could also filter by ID instead of index. Note that because of the enumeration, it's using `.1.id` for the id parameter -- `.1` is the item while `.0` is the `index`.
4. Inside the `ForEach`, the custom binding from before is created and passed to the subview
5. In the subview, instead of using @State, @Binding is used (this is what the custom `Binding` is passed to)

Using this strategy of an `ObservableObject` that contains all of your state and passes it on via @Published properties and @Bindings makes organizing your data a lot easier. It also avoids having to pass closures back and forth like you were doing initially with your `update` function. This ends up being a pretty idiomatic way of doing things in SwiftUI.